# Switch to first view controller while switching to another tab (Not Using UINavigationController)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I am new to Swift and iOS development.

When I am switching to new tab using this:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
let viewcontroller : UINavigationController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as UINavigationController
viewcontroller.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

I go on top of the stack ( the page which was open) as I am not using UINavigationController for that tab.

It gives me an error when I do this

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
var jewelleryViewController: JewelleryTableViewController!
jewelleryViewController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

that jewelleryViewController does not have a member named popToRootViewControllerAnimated. ( As it is not of type UINavigationController)

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681058/programmatically-switch-to-another-tab-and-switch-to-the-first-view-controller) but his view controllers are loaded into 5 navigation controllers unlike mine.
Is there any way I can achieve the same behaviour (of going to the first page), or do I have to change the implementation?

Thanks

Comment: You can not call popToRootViewControllerAnimated method over JewelleryViewController class object, its available only for  UINaviagtionController.

Comment: you should have separate UINavigationController for each Tab of your TabBar

Comment: Yes, I understand these. But is there any way to achieve that?