# Swift: Pop from one tab to another tab

Tags: swift

Have a tabBar Application in which there are five tabs and in one tab have added back button and i want to pop back using back button. how can it be done? have tried below code and it doesn't work

self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681058/programmatically-switch-to-another-tab-and-switch-to-the-first-view-controller

Comment: @Miteshjadav thanks